# Salesforce Mobile SDK & iOS 11 Compatibility?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilesdk

I know that iOS 11 is going to release soon. I have been searching the internet about this so that we aren't caught off guard with our iOS app that uses it but I haven't seen anything yet. Is anyone aware of potential compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

We, [MobileCaddy](https://mobilecaddy.net), have daily tests run on all Dev preview and public betas for Android and iOS. In our [August Trust Update](https://www.mobilecaddy.net/august-2017-mobilecaddy-trust-update/) it covers the release so far, and we have not seen any issues to date. As an update to this we've also not seen any issues with the more recent betas, either.

Whist the iOS release looks OK, I'd recommend you also check your app on iOS 10/9 with Winter 18, we have seen an [issue](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000UV8vQAG) with Salesforce doing something funky if you're trying to open VF pages from within your app.

Comment: So what version of the Salesforce Mobile SDK are you using? We are currently still on 5.0 and I just got iOS 11 beta on a phone and the app crashes when I click the gear button to go to the screen to select between the Production and Sandbox logins. I can login but once I grant access to site, it also crashes. Do I just need to be on 5.2 or is this something different?

Comment: Oh right. We've not moved any client apps to SDK 5+ yet (due to various reasons). From the top of my head we have SDK3+ and 4.2.X running OK.

Comment: Yeah, we are SF Mobile SDK 5.0.0. I was able to download our current app iOS app from the AppStore and run it on my phone with the iOS 11 beta, and it worked fine with everything, including the plugins. It looks like it only crashed when I built it from XCode 9 Beta. So its probably its related to XCode 9 Beta and not iOS 11.

Comment: We are using Pods and latest salesforce sdk ios pods version is 4.3.1. Does it work properly with ios11.0?